# App catalog is not showing in site collection of SharePoint Admin Center

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver, app-catalog

I am working on SharePoint add-ins to create a remote event receiver. I have generated .app file and need to deploy on my SharePoint site. I followed the following reference to create app catalog for my site.

**Reference:** [Create App Catalog In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-app-catalog-in-sharepoint-online/)

After following all the above steps, I visited to site collections of the SharePoint Admin Center to get app catalog home lisk but app catalog is not showing there.
How did I do wrong while following the reference steps?

Comment: How long did you wait?  What the reference doesn't tell you is that after initiating the creation of the App Catalog, it can take 20-30 minutes before you see it show up in the Admin interface and become officially linked as your tenant's App Catalog.  Since you posted eight hours ago, it should be showing up by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-app-catalog). It seems to me that these are the steps to follow. Can you elaborate on the problem you're facing?

Comment: thank you, your guide link helped.